# Why do I get very intense picks when I use PBE0 with NC PP?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, band-structure, electronic-structure, density-of-states

I used PBE0 to get projected density of states using norm-conserving pseudopotentials with Quantum ESPRESSO.  I found very intense picks (scf -> projwfc ) compared to the ones that I found using PBE with PAW pseudopotentials (scf -> nscf -> projwfc) .

What can be the causes of this issue please?

Comment: Hi @Camilla, in order to check for answers, could you please share your input files (all input files you used, starting from scf) first?

Comment: The peaks are usually slightly more intense with hybrid functionals, that's partly what they're for. It's not usually too dramatic though; are you using the pseudopotentials with the same core electrons, and are you using same k-point sets for the PBE0 SCF set and the PBE NSCF set?